# Sesam DTL - find entities with duplicate attributes

Tags: sesam

is it possible to find duplicate entities within the same data-set in Sesam?

for example if two or more entities have same email attribute:

input

```
[{
        _id: "1",
        "email": "foo@bar.baz"
    }, {
        _id: "2",
        "email": "foo@bar.baz"
    }
]
```

output

```
[{
        _id: "1",
        "email": "foo@bar.baz",
        "duplicate-ids": ["2"]
    }
]
```

or just merge them into one entity.
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this within Sesam with the following configuration. I've added an extra entity to show that this works:

```
{
  "_id": "customers",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "1",
      "email": "foo@bar.baz"
    }, {
      "_id": "2",
      "email": "foo@bar.baz"
    }, {
      "_id": "3",
      "email": "foo@example.org"
    }]
  }
}
```

We iterate over these entities and hop back to the same dataset to find the duplicates (I've also added a filter to only keep the ones that has duplicates, but this can be removed):

```
{
  "_id": "duplicate-emails",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "customers"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "email"],
        ["add", "duplicate-ids",
          ["filter",
            ["neq", "_.", "_S._id"],
            ["hops", {
              "datasets": ["customers c"],
              "where": [
                ["eq", "_S.email", "c.email"]
              ],
              "return": "c._id"
            }]
          ]
        ],
        ["filter",
          ["gte",
            ["count", "_T.duplicate-ids"], 1]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This yields the following two entities:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "duplicate-ids": [
        "2"
      ],
      "email": "foo@bar.baz"
   },
   {
      "_id": "2",
      "duplicate-ids": [
        "1"
      ],
      "email": "foo@bar.baz"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting multiple entities when there are duplicates you can instead group this by the property you are inspecting (in this case `email`). First we produce a new dataset for the emails:

```
{
  "_id": "customer-emails",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "customers"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "_id", "_S.email"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then we use this new dataset as the source for the alternative duplicate detector:

```
{
  "_id": "duplicate-emails2",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "customer-emails"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "customer_ids",
          ["hops", {
            "datasets": ["customers c"],
            "where": [
              ["eq", "_S._id", "c.email"]
            ],
            "return": "c._id"
          }]
        ],
        ["filter",
          ["gt",
            ["count", "_T.customer_ids"], 1]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you the following single output entity:

```
{
  "_id": "foo@bar.baz",
  "customer_ids": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```